# ListView Implemented by cursor .Error

Tags: java, android, mysql

i want to implement a listview which is populated by a SQL cursor i have successfully implemented the cursor and am having trouble adapting it 
this is my DatabaseHandler where the cursor is created

```
public Cursor fetchAllSuspects() {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_SUSPECTS, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                  KEY_NAME, KEY_SEX}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

          if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
          db.close();
          return mCursor;
         }
```

it is then called upon inmy suspectview class and implemented as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_suspectview);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); 
    Cursor lol = db.fetchAllSuspects();
list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

String[] columns = new String[] {
    //  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID,
        DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME,
        DatabaseHandler.KEY_SEX         
      };
 int[] to = new int[] { 
         //   R.id.suspect_id,
            R.id.suspect_name,
            R.id.suspect_sex
          };

 dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.suspect_list, 
            lol, 
            columns, 
            to,
            0);

 list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I recieve and error in the logcat wich states that the field ID is non existent but is present and holds 6 entries of data the logcat is below

```
05-03 19:08:19.951: D/dalvikvm(582): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-03 19:08:20.951: I/dalvikvm(582): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-03 19:08:21.101: I/dalvikvm(582): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-03 19:08:21.341: I/dalvikvm(582): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-03 19:08:21.441: I/dalvikvm(582): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-03 19:08:21.642: D/dalvikvm(582): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 120K, 3% free 9333K/9543K, paused 60ms
05-03 19:08:21.802: D/gralloc_goldfish(582): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-03 19:08:21.851: I/dalvikvm(582): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-03 19:08:21.861: I/dalvikvm(582): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-03 19:08:58.581: D/AndroidRuntime(582): Shutting down VM
05-03 19:08:58.581: W/dalvikvm(582): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sherlock/com.example.sherlock.Suspectview}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:145)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.example.sherlock.Suspectview.onCreate(Suspectview.java:42)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-03 19:08:58.601: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  ... 11 more
05-03 19:08:59.001: I/dalvikvm(582): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-03 19:08:59.012: I/dalvikvm(582): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-03 19:08:59.552: I/dalvikvm(582): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-03 19:08:59.571: I/dalvikvm(582): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

DatabaseTable

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "suspectsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_SUSPECTS = "suspects";

// Contacts Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_SEX = "sex";
public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_HAIR = "hair";
public static final String KEY_ADD = "additional";
public static final String KEY_NAT = "nationality";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
```

Further code can be made availible
thankyou in advance

Comment: Did you modify your table to add KEY_ID?

Answer (score 0):

Change you `KEY_ID = "id"` to `KEY_ID = "_id"` and change `DATABASE_VERSION` to 2 or clear your app data using System Settings.

Comment: Change was made had no effect on the outcome